# Can I run Quick Search Box from AppWidget

Tags: android, search, android-appwidget, quick-search

I have program with search interface. Search works well from activity(when I call onSearchRequested()) or from  Quick Search Box when hardware search button was pressed.

But how can I run Quick Search Box from AppWidget?

Comment: I have the same issue, the only thing i can say about this atm is that the standard "google search" widget drives you to a different activity with black BG. So the possibilities are 2: 1) it's impossible to open the search from the appWidget, 2) it's possible with some strange hack but it's not a pattern that google would follow.

both 2 options suggest to implement a new activity that start the search